# Scheduling with EventWaitHandle with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, event-wait-handle

The following piece of code has two threads each writing 20's `string str` to its corresponding textbox. Once completed, `Thread t00` signals `Thread t01` to start and change the shared `string str` from **y** to **x**. `Thread t00` should write 20 **y** to a textbox, and `Thread t01` should write 20 **x** to another textbox. Instead, `Thread t00` end up writing 19 **y** and 1 **x**.  But if I add a `Thread.Sleep()` before EventWaitHandle is set, that fixes the problem I had (I get 20 **x** and 20 **y**), but why? `EventWaitHandle` should not be set only after the loop is finished, with or without `Thread.Sleep()`.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string str = "y";
    static EventWaitHandle _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Thread t00 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                Action action00 = () =>
                {
                    tb00.AppendText(str);
                };
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action00);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(200);  // <-- why this fix the problem??
            _waitHandle.Set();
        });
        t00.Start();


        Thread t01 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Action action00 = () =>
            {
                tb01.AppendText("Waiting...\n");
            };
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action00);
            _waitHandle.WaitOne();

            str = "x";
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                Action action = () =>
                {
                    tb01.AppendText(str);
                };
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
            }
        });
        t01.Start();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `BeginInvoke`. `BeginInvoke` invokes delegate on UI thread asynchronously. It puts a message to UI thread message queue and returns, so the fact it returned does not mean action was actually executed.

For that reason, in most cases, when you set a wait handle and another thread recieves singal and changes `str` from `y` to `x` - there is still non-invoked `tb00.AppendText(str);` delegate in UI thread queue. When it finally is invoked - `str` is already `x`.

`Thread.Sleep` "fixes" that, because it gives some time for that pending delegate to execute on UI thread. Using `Invoke` instead of `BeginInvoke` also "fixes" that, because `Invoke` is synchronous and returns only after delegate has actually been executed on UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Think of `BeginInvoke()` pushing a unit of work into a queue. When the 20th `action00` is popped from the work queue and executed, the `str='x'` has already executed, and so when the `action00` is actually run, it will print an `x`.

The `Thread.Sleep(200)` gives the 20th `action00` time to be popped and run before the `str='x'` is execute, hence it will print a `y`.